# Why unable to execute katoolin in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed katoolin on my laptop asus A450L but when I type 'katolin', I got this:

```
root@ridz-X450LD:/home/ridz# git clone https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin.git
fatal: destination path 'katoolin' already exists and is not an empty directory.
root@ridz-X450LD:/home/ridz# sudo cp katoolin/katoolin.py /usr/bin/katoolin
root@ridz-X450LD:/home/ridz# sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/katoolin
root@ridz-X450LD:/home/ridz# sudo katoolin
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/katoolin: No such file or directory
root@ridz-X450LD:/home/ridz#
```

I dont know why? Anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `katoolin` in your /home/$USER/bin (create folder if needed) and then add this in your `.bashrc`

```
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

open a new terminal and it should work!